# Why the image is much better on browser?

Tags: linux, browser, images

I've set an wallpaper for my i3 using `feh`, but i've noticed that the colors of the image were a bit strange. Seeing on `feh` or `display`, the image is much less vivid than when seeing it locally on the browser (`qutebrowser`)

That never occurred with any image, only with that specific `jpg`

I tried to convert it to `png`, but that only made it less vivid on the browser too.

[image: The actual image]
<sub>(source: [place4plays.ru](https://place4plays.ru/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5-4.jpg))</sub>

Browser on the left, Feh on the right
[image: Browser on the left, Feh on the right]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image has an ICC color profile attached (specifically the "Adobe RGB" profile; the system default is usually "sRGB"). Some programs adjust colors according to the embedded profile; some only recognize certain ICC versions; and some ignore the profile entirely. Generally web browsers are better at applying the ICC adjustments than "super-lightweight" image viewers.

And the behavior of `magick convert` seems to differ between converting JPEG→JPEG and JPEG→PNG for some reason. It seems the former preserves all data and metadata, and the latter throws away the embedded profile without applying it, but I don't quite understand the results myself.

Either way, to permanently retain these colors, you'll probably want to force conversion to sRGB:

```
magick convert File.jpg -profile /usr/share/color/icc/colord/sRGB.icc +profile \* Output.png
```

...or not, because the original artwork on Pixiv (https://pixiv.net/i/40514719) *does not* have these vivid colors either – the adjustment was made by whoever cropped/stretched/uploaded  it to the wallpaper website.